# Removing first occurrence of a string in a file with sed on mac

Tags: bash, sed

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356239/sed-command-to-remove-first-occurrence-of-a-word) I found the command and it works without any command substitution. But if I try to substitute a variable in the command, I get the following problems.

Note: I am using sed command(BSD OSX) / MacOS

To reproduce just create a file.txt with this:

```
SOME_TEXT
CHANGE_THIS
CHANGE_THIS
CHANGE_THIS
```

Add TMP variable in you terminal:

```
TMP=export PATH=/Users/Name/with pace/and_variables:$PATH
```

Now with this command:

```
sed -i '' "1h; 1 $ { x; s/CHANGE_THIS/$TMP/; p; }" file.txt
```

I get this error:

```
sed: 1: "1h; 1 $ { x; s/CHANGE_T ...": invalid command code $
```

In a privious answer I got this("," added to "1,$":

```
sed -i '' "1h; 1,$ { x; s/CHANGE_THIS/$TMP/; p; }" file.txt
```

expected output file.txt

```
SOME_TEXT
export PATH=/Users/Name/with pace/and_variables:$PATH
CHANGE_THIS
CHANGE_THIS
```

I get this:

```
SOME_TEXT
SOME_TEXT
SOME_TEXT
SOME_TEXT
```

Comment: Why use a variable at all, when you can just paste the text directly into the sed command? If you really want to do it like this, try `"$TMP"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following if you are ok with `awk`.

```
##Creating shell variable named TM here.
TMP="export PATH=/Users/Name/with pace/and_variables:$PATH"
awk -v tmp="$TMP" '/CHANGE_THIS/ && ++flag==1{$0=tmp} 1' Input_file
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file itself then append `> temp_file && mv temp_file  Input_file` in above code too.

Adding explanation for above code too here.

```
awk -v tmp="$TMP" '              ##Creating an awk variable named tmp whose value is bash variable TMP value.
/CHANGE_THIS/ && ++flag==1{      ##Checking condition if a line is having string CHANGE_THIS and variable flag value is 1 then do following.
  $0=tmp                         ##Setting current line value to value of tmp awk variable here.
}                                ##Closing the block for condition here.
1                                ##By mentioning 1 printing edited/non-edited line here.
' Input_file                     ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thanks it works - just printing to console - I now do "awk ..." >> newfile.txt

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
sed -i '0,/.*CHANGE_THIS.*/s//my changed line/' file
```

Comment: MacOS `sed` does not support the GNU `sed` extension `0,`